# Как получить данную страницу через file_get_contents()

Tags: php

Есть [страница](https://superonlineshoping.com/page/c932ee4a4a8b692dd0a772d147df319a59e4fa28/), которая открывается в браузере. Но если получить ее через file_get_contents(), то получается страница с бесконечной перезагрузкой. Возможно ли обойти данную защиту? Там js определяет или разрешение экрана, или еще что-то.

Comment: Отключи js и обнови страницу, будет так же перезагружаться?

Comment: а, может, curl ?

Answer (score 0):

Исходник этой страницы содержит только js без каких либо данных.
Соответственно js загружает данные после выполнения.
Чтобы получить в php скрипте данные страницы - нужно страницу загрузить и выполнить js. Для этих целей, смотри в сторону phantomjs для php. Он может эту задачу решить.